# Querying 2 tables for all results

Tags: sql

I have a sql qustion. its suppose to be simple but i cant figure it out.
I have 2 tables:

```
**customer1 -** 
id      name
1       aaa
2       bbb
3       ccc
4       ddd

**customer2**-
id      name
1       aaa
2       bbb
5       eee
6       fff
```

I need to get ALL the customers in both tables.
i need to query in a way that if a customer is on both tables I will see him twice in the results (e.g aaa, bbb), and all the rest only one.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you share the result you expect to get for this sample?

Comment: what dbms are you using, sql server, oracle, mysql...? - tag you question.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to **UNION** and **UNION ALL** , with the first one you will not get duplicate , with the second one you will get even duplicate as result of your query.

Let's talk about the performance :
A **UNION** is highly optimized and really fast, except in cases where one query finishes long before the other, and you have to  wait to get the whole result set.

When you don't mind about duplicates , **UNION ALL** will be faster.

Comment: thanks, 
do you know if UNION ALL is possible in mySql as well??

Comment: MySQL has both, as should nearly all RDBMS engines.  Which is what @Raghavendrakedlaya used in their example.

Comment: link to mysql union all: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/union_all.php

Comment: weird, im getting a red mark next to 'ALL' word in mysql in phpmyadmin.

Comment: and im not getting duplicate values as i want

Comment: Yah it was just a phpmyadmin version issue, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, name from customer1
union all
select id, name from customer2
```

Comment: with this query i dont get result twice as i wanted and i only get each row once as a union.

Comment: Extremely odd `union all` should  return all data from both tables.  so if customer1 had 10 records and customer2 had 5 you'd end up with 15 containing the desired duplicates!

Comment: Tried it, it worked for me. Got 8 result with the duplicates. Using mysql 5.7

Answer (score 0):

I would have put this as a comment to : Raghavendra Kedlaya post; but it wouldn't let me.

I like to know from whence the data came when using union all..

```
SELECT id, name, 'Customer1' as src 
FROM customer1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, name, 'Customer2' as src
FROM customer2
```